# Python versions clean-up

Tags: python, bash, anaconda

I am a bit confused. I recently deleted Anaconda as part of an attempt to clean up my laptop.

As a result:

```
python
```

returns

```
-bash: /anaconda3/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

and

```
echo $PATH
```

returns

```
/Users/user1/.opam/4.10.0/bin:/Users/user1/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/user1/.local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

I assume I need to change path. How does one change path making sure one changes all the paths?

And then my second question is that

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

returns

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    65K Mar 19 00:31 /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel   925B Aug 18  2018 /usr/bin/python-config*
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B Oct 20  2018 /usr/bin/python2.7@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    82B Oct 20  2018 /usr/bin/python2.7-config@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    65K Mar 19 00:31 /usr/bin/pythonw*
 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76B Oct 20  2018 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

How does one go about deleting pythonw files without messing up the computer?

**Edit**

- restarting the terminal fixed the first issue ty
- replying to @cel I would like to delete the pythonw because it seems like they should not be there - they are redundant

Comment: The `No such file` error  is just a cashing issue, try `hash -r` or restarting the shell and it should be gone. You don't necessarily have to clean up the path.
Regarding the second part: do not attempt to manually delete files in `/usr/` - try giving some information why you want to delete them and maybe we can help.